# iPad Modal View Dismissal Changes Parent View Orientation

Tags: ipad, rotation, modal-dialog, orientation

I have an iPad Split View Application that brings up a modal view to display certain content. When I bring up the modal (in PageSheet style) and then change from Portrait to Landscape (or vice-versa) and then dismiss the modal the orientation of the detailViewController (the parent of the modal) turns 90 degrees.

So if I am in landscape mode when I close the modal the right pane will turn as if it were in portrait mode but the device is still in Landscape and the rootViewController is still visible. After this happens no rotation will solve the problem until the view is removed.

Any idea what I've screwed up here? I've had a ton of trouble with iPad rotation handling in general but this one is really giving me problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are presenting the modal view from either of the two sub-views of the `SplitViewController`, then you will have the orientation problems. Just present the modal view from the `SplitViewController`.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks so much I hadn't even thought of trying that.